# Flink 1.14.3 Rack Aware Flink Task Manager

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to implement a rack-aware kafka consumer that connects to kafka broker that is in the same AZ as the Flink task manager. I'm trying to find any such documentation - there is no default implementation but I would like to add this to reduce data transfer costs on our platform.
Our flink cluster is deployed via the Spotify Flink Operator.

Can someone point me to any such implementation? I have tried the following and it doesn't work:

1. In the DAG creation phase, get the AZ for current pod,
2. Assign that AZ as the rack in the Kafka consumer property
3. Apply this DAG and let the job run.

Example of what I am looking to do. Say there are 3 task managers and they are running in az1, az2 and az2 respectively. Now, each of these task managers should connect to the rack that correspond to az1, az2 and az3 respectively.

```
`client.rack`
```